# How register Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService at IServiceCollection

Tags: asp.net-core, exchangewebservices

I implemented a `CalendarService` in my asp.net core project which provides functions to get data from an exchange server. For calling the exchange server I'm using the lib from NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.NETStandard

At the moment I create the instance of `ExchangeService` inside the `CalendarService` class with credentials inside it. But I want register the `CalendarService` in the `Startup` class.

```
namespace API.Infrastructure.Services
{
    class CalendarService : ICalendarService
    {
        private readonly ExchangeService _exchangeService;

        public CalendarService ()
        {
            _exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
            _exchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password", "domain");
            _exchangeService.Url = new Uri("https://xxx/Exchange.asmx")
        }

        public Task<Termin> GetEventsBasedOnSearchCritera(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            /// ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want register the `CalendarService` via `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method from  `Startup.cs` class like the `GitHubService` with its `HttpClient` example at https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#typed-clients but `IServiceCollection` doesn't provide a method to add an `ExchangeService`.

Has someone any idea how can register the ExchangeService in the Startup class?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the factory overload of the `AddSingleton`, `AddScoped`, or `AddTransient` methods. I'm not sure what scope `ExchangeService` should be registered in, but it *seems* like something that could be a singleton. The methodology is the same regardless of the scope, though:

```
services.AddSingleton(p =>
{
    var config = p.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
    var username = config["ExchangeService:UserName"];
    var password = config["ExchangeService:Password"];
    var domain = config["ExchangeService:Domain"];
    var url = config["ExchangeService:Url"];

    var exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
    exchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password, domain);
    exchangeService.Url = new Uri(url);
    return exchangeService;
});
```

Comment: Yeah of course, you're great. That's what I want! Thx u very much!